# Как очищать canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Я отредактировал код под себя.

Вопрос как удалять картинки что остаются на фоне? Я начинающий разработчик и не силён в canvas. Прошу вас помочь. Буду очень благодарен за любой совет, помощь.

```js
var totalImages = 96,
  canv = document.getElementById('video_img_anim'),
  canv_images = canv.dataset.img,
  context_imgset = canv.getContext('2d'),
  images = [];

canv_images = canv_images.split(' ')
canv_images.forEach(img_src => {
  var img = document.createElement('img')

  if (img_src != NaN && img_src != " " && img_src != "" && img_src != undefined) {
    img.src = img_src
    images.push(img)
  }
});

var currentLocation = 0;

var setImage = function(newLocation) {
  context_imgset.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
}

var wheelDistance = function(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  var w = evt.wheelDelta,
    d = evt.detail;
  if (d) {
    if (w) return w / d / 40 * d > 0 ? 1 : -1; // Opera
    else return -d / 3; // Firefox;         TODO: do not /3 for OS X
  } else return w / 120; // IE/Safari/Chrome TODO: /3 for Chrome OS X
}

var wheelDirection = function(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  return (evt.detail < 0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1;
};

var MouseWheelHandler = function(e) {

  // The following equation will return either a 1 for scroll down
  // or -1 for a scroll up
  var distance = wheelDistance(e);
  var direction = wheelDirection(e);

  // This code mostly keeps us from going too far in either direction
  currentLocation -= Math.round(distance * 3);
  if (currentLocation < 0) currentLocation = 0;
  if (currentLocation >= images.length)
    currentLocation = images.length - 1;

  setImage(currentLocation);
};

// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera,  Firefox
window.addEventListener("wheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);

setImage(4);
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133434/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для очистки холста от предыдущего изображения, можно использовать метод [`.clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect), который зальет указанную область прозрачным черным цветом.

```js
var totalImages = 96,
  canv = document.getElementById('video_img_anim'),
  canv_images = canv.dataset.img,
  context_imgset = canv.getContext('2d'),
  images = [];

canv_images = canv_images.split(' ')
canv_images.forEach(img_src => {
  var img = document.createElement('img')

  if (img_src != NaN && img_src != " " && img_src != "" && img_src != undefined) {
    img.src = img_src
    images.push(img)
  }
});

var currentLocation = 0;

var setImage = function(newLocation) {
  context_imgset.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height); // стираем
  context_imgset.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, canv.width, canv.height); // рисуем
}


requestAnimationFrame(function animate() {
  setImage(currentLocation);
  currentLocation = (currentLocation + 1) % images.length;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
});
```

```html
<canvas width="380" height="180" class="video_img_anim" id="video_img_anim" data-img="https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation73.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation74.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation75.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation76.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation77.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation78.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation79.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation80.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation81.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation82.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation83.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation84.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation85.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation86.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation87.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation88.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation89.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation90.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation91.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation92.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation93.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation94.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation95.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation00.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation01.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation02.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation03.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation04.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation05.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation06.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation07.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation08.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation09.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation10.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation11.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation12.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation13.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation14.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation15.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation16.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation17.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation18.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation19.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation20.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation21.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation22.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation23.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation24.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation25.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation26.png"></canvas>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Допилил в своем примере.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли разобраться в вопросе. Я использовал clearRect. Вот решение:

```js
var totalImages = 96,
  canv = document.getElementById('video_img_anim'),
  canv_images = canv.dataset.img,
  context_imgset = canv.getContext('2d'),
  images = [];

canv_images = canv_images.split(' ')
canv_images.forEach(img_src => {
  var img = document.createElement('img')

  if (img_src != NaN && img_src != " " && img_src != "" && img_src != undefined) {
    img.src = img_src
    images.push(img)
  }
});

var currentLocation = 0;

var setImage = function(newLocation) {
  context_imgset.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  context_imgset.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
}

var wheelDistance = function(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  var w = evt.wheelDelta,
    d = evt.detail;
  if (d) {
    if (w) return w / d / 40 * d > 0 ? 1 : -1; // Opera
    else return -d / 3; // Firefox;         TODO: do not /3 for OS X
  } else return w / 120; // IE/Safari/Chrome TODO: /3 for Chrome OS X
}

var wheelDirection = function(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  return (evt.detail < 0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1;
};

var MouseWheelHandler = function(e) {

  // The following equation will return either a 1 for scroll down
  // or -1 for a scroll up
  var distance = wheelDistance(e);
  var direction = wheelDirection(e);

  // This code mostly keeps us from going too far in either direction
  currentLocation -= Math.round(distance * 3);
  if (currentLocation < 0) currentLocation = 0;
  if (currentLocation >= images.length)
    currentLocation = images.length - 1;

  setImage(currentLocation);
};

// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera,  Firefox
window.addEventListener("wheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);

setImage(4);
```

```html
<canvas width="380" height="380" class="video_img_anim" id="video_img_anim" data-img="https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation73.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation74.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation75.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation76.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation77.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation78.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation79.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation80.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation81.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation82.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation83.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation84.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation85.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation86.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation87.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation88.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation89.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation90.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation91.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation92.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation93.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation94.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation95.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation00.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation01.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation02.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation03.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation04.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation05.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation06.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation07.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation08.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation09.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation10.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation11.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation12.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation13.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation14.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation15.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation16.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation17.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation18.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation19.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation20.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation21.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation22.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation23.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation24.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation25.png https://picpig.ru/images/2022/01/22/Home_Homecenter_Animation26.png"></canvas>
```